# admob is not defined - Cordova CLI

Tags: android, cordova, admob, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins

I'm tring to include admob ads to my app. I'm using Cordova CLI to build my android app.

using `cordova plugin add cordova-admob --save`
from the documentations I have installed admob plugin using cordova cli also have included the plugin in the config.xml. And made all the required configs using ad ids.

But after when I run the app in device and inspect. I see

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: admob is not defined
```

How to make admob available to window. My understanding was adding plugin tag to config.xml will take care of it. But it seems to be not correctly working. Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cordova and AdMob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40611226/cordova-and-admob)

Comment: @NensiKasundra  I'm able to setup everything but only I could not access admob